# What is wrong with query Mysql?

Tags: mysql

There is an trivial SQL query:

```
SELECT enterprise_invoces.AC_name, 
enterprise_invoces.AC_id, 
enterprise_invoces.AC_code, 
ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount>0, AT_amount, 0)) AS debit,
ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount <0, AT_amount, 0)) AS credit 
    FROM account_transactions 
    INNER JOIN enterprise_invoces ON enterprise_invoces.AC_id = account_transactions.AT_code
```

I get this error message:

```
> # 1064 - You have an error in the request. Check the MySQL version documentation for correct syntax near 'FROM account_transactions INNER
> JOIN enterprise_invoces ON enterprise_invoces.AC' on line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close brackets:

```
SELECT enterprise_invoces.AC_name, 
  enterprise_invoces.AC_id, 
  enterprise_invoces.AC_code, 
  ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount>0, AT_amount, 0))) AS debit,  --here
  ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount <0, AT_amount, 0))) AS credit  -- here
FROM account_transactions 
JOIN enterprise_invoces 
  ON enterprise_invoces.AC_id = account_transactions.AT_code
 GROUP BY enterprise_invoces.AC_name,
          enterprise_invoces.AC_id,
          enterprise_invoces.AC_code   -- there should be corresponding `GROUP BY`
```